# The type or namespace name 'DatabaseContext' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```cs
class DatabaseContext:DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options):base(options)
    {

    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>
}
```

I have tried uninstall then reinstall EntityFrameworkCore.But It didnt work.How can I fix it.Thank you in advance

Comment: Try to set the `DatabaseContext` class access modifier to `public`. By default it's `internal`. So if you are trying to access it from another project you will get this error.

Comment: You can read [DbContext in dependency injection for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core) to know more about DbContext  in asp.net core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Classes, records, and structs declared directly within a namespace (in
> other words, that aren't nested within other classes or structs) can
> be either `public` or `internal`. `internal` is the default if no access
> modifier is specified.

[Class, record, and struct member accessibility](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#class-record-and-struct-accessibility)

Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly they are defined: [`internal` (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)